# I am trying to convert an Excel spread sheet to C#.Net interface, there is a line that confuse me Can everyone explain me the logic behind this line

Tags: excel

I am trying to convert an Excel spread sheet to C#.Net interface, there is a line that confuse me Can everyone explain me the logic behind this line

```
=IF($N$247="0.","G91",CONCATENATE("G91 A",$W$247,". X",$N$247," L",$O$247))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

If the cell N247 has a value of "0" then return the value in cell G91, otherwise return a concatenation of the following: "G91 ", cell W247, ". X", cell N247, " L", cell O247

Comment: Thanks. That make sense